# ID of Front-Page

Tags: id, frontpage

I like to get the ID of the selected front page.
My page uses an Template for that page.
I've read about `get_option('page_on_front')`, but this didn't work for me.

Is there any function to get this ID?

Comment: What does the 'page_on_front' option return for you?

Comment: Why/in what way doesn't it work?

Comment: It returns nothing

Comment: On the `Settings -> Reading` admin page, is "A static page" selected on "Front page displays", and is a page selected in the "Front page" dropdown?

Comment: Yes and I want the ID of exactly this page :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
global $wp_query;
$post = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
$post->ID;
```

This'll give you the ID for each page you're on.

`get_option( 'page_on_front' )` should've worked though.

Comment: $post = $wp_query->get_queried_object(); $post->ID;  Worked fine for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could either go into your Dashboard > 'Pages' and then hover over the page that is using the front page template and hover over the title - on the bottom left of your screen you will see a string of information like this:

```
http://yourdomain.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=724&action=edit
```

Post=724, that part will be the ID of that page.

Or programmatically you could use this function and pass the slug of this page using the front page template:

```
    function royal_get_id($page_slug) {

    $page = get_page_by_path($page_slug);

    if ($page) {

        return $page->ID;
    } else {

        return null;
    }
}

$value = royal_get_id('your-homepage-slug');
echo $value;
```

Comment: Yes of course I can get the ID in the URL. But it should be dynamic depending on the settings in the backend. Your function returns a wrong ID for me?

Answer (score 0):

What you doing is correct then, just store it in a variable to use as you need to.

Also make sure you have set the page as the front page in your dashboard under 'Settings' > Reading or else this value will be empty as it is not set.

```
$front_id = get_option('page_on_front');
    echo $front_id;
```